# Uniqueness of the "algebraic closure" of a commutative ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, uniqueness-theorems

There are several ways to generalize the notion of "algebraic closure" from fields to arbitrary commutative rings. A good overview is [On algebraic closures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43737179) by R. Raphael. I am more interested in the notion suggested in [Stacks/0DCK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DCK). In particular, I would like to know if there is a corresponding "algebraic closure" which is unique up to isomorphism - as in the case of fields.

A commutative ring $R$ is *absolutely integrally closed* if every monic polynomial over $R$ has a root in $R$. Equivalently, every monic polynomial over $R$ is a product of linear factors over $R$. (Notice that this differs from E. Enoch's notion of [totally integrally closed rings](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1968-019-03/S0002-9939-1968-0224600-9/S0002-9939-1968-0224600-9.pdf).)

It is easy to prove ([Stacks/0DCR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DCR)) that every commutative ring $R$ has an integral extension $R \hookrightarrow R'$ such that $R'$ is absolutely integrally closed (and $R'$ is a free $R$-module, among other things). But clearly such an extension is not unique: Take any ideal $I \subseteq R'$ with $I \cap R = 0$, then $R \hookrightarrow R'/I$ has the same properties. So we have to make this extension tighter...

Recall that an extension $R \hookrightarrow R'$ is *tight* (aka *essential*) if for all ideals $I \subseteq R'$ we have $I \cap R = 0 \implies I =0$. If $R \hookrightarrow R'$ is any extension, there is always an ideal $J \subseteq R'$ which is maximal with the property $J \cap R = 0$ (Zorn's Lemma), and then $R \hookrightarrow R'/J$ is tight.

So for every commutative ring $R$ there is a tight integral ring extension $R \hookrightarrow R^{\text{aic}}$ such that $R^{\text{aic}}$ is absolutely integrally closed.

**Question.** Does this determine $R^{\text{aic}}$ up to isomorphism? If not, what properties do we need to add to make it unique?

The end result should be called the absolute integral closure of $R$, for short a.i.c. (Unfortunately, the name is already taken for [something else](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0441.pdf) when $R$ is a domain.)

*Edit*. Actually the answer by Matthé proves that the a.i.c. in the case of a domain is what is already understood under this name, namely the integral closure inside the algebraic closure of the field of fractions. In this special case uniqueness holds.

*Edit.* Some simple facts:

(a) The a.i.c of a field is uniquely determined. It is the algebraic closure. (This is because every tight extension of a field is also a field.)

(b) If $R_1,\dotsc,R_n$ are commutative rings whose a.i.c. is uniquely determined, is straight forward to check that $R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n$ has a uniquely determined a.i.c. as well, with $(R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n)^{\text{aic}} = R_1^{\text{aic}} \times \cdots \times R_n^{\text{aic}}$.

(c) If $S \subseteq R$ is a multiplicative subset consisting of regular elements and $R^{\text{aic}}$ is some a.i.c. of $R$, then $S^{-1} R^{\text{aic}}$ is an a.i.c. of $S^{-1} R$. I'm not sure yet about uniqueness here, though.

Comment: For one thing, you must in some way demand that as few units exist as possible. For if $A$ is aic and tight over $R$ and $S$ $\subseteq$ $A$ is multiplicatively closed and saturated (if $st$ $\in$ $S$ then $s$ or $t$ is in $S$) and no $s$ $\in$ $S$ annihilates a non-zero $r$ $\in$ $R$, then $S^{-1}A$ is aic and tight over $R$. E.g., both the ring of algebraic integers and  the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ are absolutely integrally closed and tight over $R$ $=$ $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee I demand the extensions to be integral. The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Abstract-nonsensical approach would be to characterize injective objects in commutative rings and take injective hulls. When it exists, injective hull is unique up to a (non-unique) isomorphism

Comment: I think we can only expect injectivity with respect to integral ring extensions. But this is then Enoch's notion of totally integrally closed rings.

Comment: You mean the class of monos with respect to which your absolutely integrally closed rings are injective is the same with respect to which totally integrally closed rings are injective?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume $R$ is reduced and $\mathrm{min}(R)$, the set of minimal prime ideals, is finite. Then $R$ has a *universal* aic, one in which every aic of $R$ can be embedded. We show this below.

Rings of this type have quite remarkable properties, and they include all Noetherian reduced rings. Domains are just the special case where $\mathrm{min}(R)$ is a one-point space. For if $\mathrm{min}(R)$ $=$ $\{\mathfrak{p}\}$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $\bigcap\mathrm{min}(R)$ $=$ $\bigcap\mathrm{spec}(R)$ $=$ $\mathrm{nil}(R)$ $=$ $0$.

Let $R$ $\subseteq$ $S$ be a given tight integral extension, with $S$ an absolutely integrally closed ring. Then we have $\mathrm{nil}(S)\cap R$ $=$ $\mathrm{nil}(R)$ $=$ $0$, so by tightness $S$ must also be reduced.

For $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, we can find a $\mathfrak{P}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{spec}(S)$ with $\mathfrak{P}\cap R$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}$, because the extension $R$ $\subseteq$ $S$ is integral. Take a minimal prime ideal $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathfrak{P}$ of $S$. Then $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}\cap R$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}$. If $I$ $=$ $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)}\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$, then $I\cap R$ $=$ $\bigcap\mathrm{min}(R)$ $=$ $\mathrm{nil}(R)$ $=$ $0$, hence $I$ $=$ $0$. So if $\mathfrak{Q}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(S)$, since $\mathrm{min}(R)$ is finite, the product $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)}\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ exists and is contained in $I$ $=$ $0$ $\subseteq$ $\mathfrak{Q}$. Thus  $\mathfrak{Q}$ must be one of the $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$. Therefore, $S$ is also "semiglobal", that is to say, $\mathrm{min}(S)$ $=$ $\{\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}\mid\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)\}$ is finite.

Let $K$ and $L$ be the total rings of fractions of $R$ and $S$, respectively. So $K$ $=$ $\mathrm{reg}(R)^{-1}R$, where $\mathrm{reg}(R)$ is the set of regular elements of $R$. The prime ideals of $K$ are of the form $\mathfrak{p}K$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{spec}(R)$ with $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathrm{reg}(R)$ $=$ $\varnothing$, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}$ consists of zero divisors of $R$. These $\mathfrak{p}$ are precisely the minimal prime ideals of $R$. For if $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$ and $r$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$, then $r$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$. Being a localisation of a reduced ring, $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is again reduced. So $0$ $=$ $\mathrm{nil}(R_\mathfrak{p})$ $=$ $\bigcap\mathrm{spec}(R_\mathfrak{p})$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$, for $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$ is the only prime ideal of $R_\mathfrak{p}$. (Note that $R_\mathfrak{p}$ therefore must be a field.) So $r$ $=$ $0$ in $R_\mathfrak{p}$, and hence there is an $r'$ $\in$ $R-\mathfrak{p}$ for which $rr'$ $=$ $0$ in $R$. So $r$ is a zero divisor of $R$. Conversely, if $rr'$ $=$ $0$ and $r'$ $\ne$ $0$, then there is a $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$ with $r'$ $\notin$ $\mathfrak{p}$, because $\bigcap\mathrm{min}(R)$ $=$ $0$. Therefore, $r$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$. So if a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $R$ contains only zero divisors, it is contained in $\bigcup\mathrm{min}(R)$. But this a finite union, and so by the [prime avoidance lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00DS) the ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ is a minimal prime of $R$.

So $\mathrm{spec}(K)$ $=$ $\{ \mathfrak{p}K\mid\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)\}$. And $R$ $\subseteq$ $K$, for if $r$ $\in$ $R$ becomes zero in $K$, there is an $r'$ $\in$ $\mathrm{reg}(R)$ with $rr'$ $=$ $0$, hence $r$ $=$ $0$.

Note that $\mathfrak{p}K\cap R$ $=$ $\mathfrak{p}$ when $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime. Indeed, if $r=u/v$ in $K$ with $u$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$ and $v$ $\in$ $R$ regular, then there is a $w$ $\in$ $\mathrm{reg}(R)$ with $w(vr-u)$ $=$ $0$ in $R$, so $vr$ $=$ $u$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$. If $v$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$, then by the above $v$ is a zero divisor of $R$, contradiction. So $r$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$. As a result, $R/\mathfrak{p}$ $\subseteq$ $K/\mathfrak{p}K$.

It follows that $K$ is a zero-dimensional reduced ring, that is, a von Neumann regular ring. For if $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ are minimals of $R$ with $\mathfrak{p}K$ $\subseteq$ $\mathfrak{q}K$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ $\subseteq$ $\mathfrak{q}K\cap R$ $=$ $\mathfrak{q}$, hence $\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $\mathfrak{q}$. So if $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, we have $\mathfrak{p}K$ $\in$ $\mathrm{max}(K)$, and so $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ is a field. It is in fact the quotient field of $R/\mathfrak{p}$. The ring $L$ is also VNR, and it contains $S$ as a subring.

$R\subseteq S\subseteq L=\mathrm{reg}(S)^{-1}S$, and $\mathrm{reg}(R)$ $\subseteq$ $\mathrm{reg}(S)$. For if $rs$ $=$ $0$ with $r$ $\in$ $R$ and $s$ $\in$ $S-\{0\}$, then $r$ is in a minimal prime $\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $S$. But then $r$ $\in$ $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, so $r$ is a zero divisor in $R$. Thus $K$ $=$ $\mathrm{reg}(R)^{-1}R$ $\subseteq$ $\mathrm{reg}(R)^{-1}S$ (since localizations are flat) $\subseteq$ $\mathrm{reg}(S)^{-1}S$ $=$ $L$. Hence $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ is a subfield of $L/\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}L$. And the extension $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ $\subseteq$ $L/\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}L$ is algebraic, because $S$ is integral over $R$.

The natural map $K\to\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)}K/\mathfrak{p}K$ is injective, for the kernel is the intersection of all prime ideals of $K$, and $K$ is reduced. As $\mathrm{dim}(K)$ $=$ $0$, by the CRT this is actually an isomorphism, and $K$ is a finite product of fields. It is easy to see that in fact $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ $\cong$ $K_{\mathfrak{p}K}$ $\cong$ $R_\mathfrak{p}$.

Let $\overline{K}$ $=$ $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)}C_\mathfrak{p}$, where $C_\mathfrak{p}$ is the algebraic closure of the field $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ (and of $L/\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}L$). This $\overline{K}$ may be regarded as the "algebraic closure" of $R$ (or, equally, of $K$, $S$ or $L$).

I claim that the integral closure $T$ of $R$ in $\overline{K}$ is tight over $R$. For let $I$ be a nonzero ideal of $T$, and take $0$ $\neq$ $t$ $\in$ $I$. For $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, denote the $\mathfrak{p}$-th coordinate of $t$ by $t_\mathfrak{p}$, and pick a $\mathfrak{p}$ with $t_\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $C_\mathfrak{p}$ nonzero. Take a monic $f$ $\in$ $R[X]$ with $f(t)$ $=$ $0$ in $T$. If the constant term $f(0)$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$, it becomes zero in $K/\mathfrak{p}K$, hence in $C_\mathfrak{p}$. As $t_\mathfrak{p}$ is a root of the image of $f$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}[X]$ and $C_\mathfrak{p}$ is a field, $t_\mathfrak{p}$ is also a root of (the image of) $g$ $=$ $(f-f(0))/X$ $\in$ $R[X]$. We then replace $f$ by $g$. If the new $f(0)$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$ again, repeat the process until $f(0)$ $\notin$ $\mathfrak{p}$.

By the finiteness of the minimal spectrum of $R$, the product of the minimal primes $\mathfrak{q}$ $\ne$ $\mathfrak{p}$ cannot be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$, so there exists a $c$ $\in$ $R$ that is in all minimals of $R$ except $\mathfrak{p}$. Put $h$ $:=$ $cf$. Then $h(t_\mathfrak{p})$ $=$ $0$, and for $\mathfrak{p}$ $\ne$ $\mathfrak{q}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, we have $c$ $=$ $0$ in $K/\mathfrak{q}K$, so $h$ $=$ $0$ in $C_\mathfrak{q}[X]$. Hence $h(t)$ $=$ $0$ in $T$. But $h(0)$ $=$ $cf(0)$ $\notin$ $\mathfrak{p}$, and therefore $h(0)$ is a nonzero element of $tT$ $\subseteq$ $I$ that is in $R$. This settles tightness.

Since $T$ is integral over $R$ and clearly absolutely integrally closed, it is an absolute integral closure of $R$. The image of $S$ in $\overline{K}$ under the composition map $S\subseteq L\rightarrowtail\prod_{\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)}L/\tilde{\mathfrak{p}}L$ $\subseteq$ $\overline{L}$ $=$ $\overline{K}$ is integral over $R$, so it is contained in $T$.

An $e\in\overline{K}$ is idempotent iff for all $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$ its $\mathfrak{p}$-th coordinate is either $0$ or $1$. Clearly, the idempotents are integral over $R$, hence they are in $T$, and there are $2^{|\mathrm{min}(R)|}$ of them. Denote the one with $e_\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $1$ and $0$ elsewhere by $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$. Then every idempotent is the sum of the elements of a subset of $\{e_{(\mathfrak{p})}\mid\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{min}(R)\}$. And $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}e_{(\mathfrak{q})}$ $=$ $0$ when $\mathfrak{p}$ $\ne$ $\mathfrak{q}$. So the $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ form what is known as a fundamental system of orthogonal idempotents.

Then $S=T$ iff the $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ are all in $S$. For if they are, and $t$ $\in$ $T$, fix a $\mathfrak{p}$, and let $f$ $\in$ $R[X]$ be monic with $f(t)$ $=$ $0$. Then $f(t_\mathfrak{p})$ $=$ $0$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}$. Write $f$ $=$ $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(X-s_i)$ in $S[X]$, so that we have $f$ $=$ $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(X-(s_i)_{\mathfrak{p}})$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}[X]$. But then $t_\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $(s_i)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for some $i$, because $C_\mathfrak{p}$ is a field. Put $s$ $=$ $s_i$. Since $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ is in $S$, so is $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}s$. Its $\mathfrak{p}$-th component is $t_\mathfrak{p}$, and it has zero for the other $\mathfrak{q}$. So $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}s$ is actually equal to $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}t$. The sum of the $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$, taken over the $\mathfrak{p}$ $\in$ $\mathrm{min}(R)$, is equal to $1$. So $t$, which is therefore the sum of the $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}t$, must be in $S$.

Note that, by integrality, lying-over holds for $S/R$. So when $R$ is a domain, there's a prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $S$ with $\mathfrak{q}\cap R$ $=$ $0$. As $S$ is tight over $R$, we have $\mathfrak{q}$ $=$ $0$, so $S$ is a domain. Hence it contains $2^{|\mathrm{min}(R)|}$ idempotents, namely just the trivial ones, $0$ and $1$.

To sum up:

**1) $\boldsymbol{T}$ is the universal aic of $\boldsymbol{R}$. That is to say, it contains all other aic's.**

**2) An aic of $\boldsymbol{R}$ is isomorphic to $\boldsymbol{T}$ iff it contains $\boldsymbol{2^{|\mathrm{min}(R)|}}$ idempotents.**

**3) Domains have uniquely determined aic's.**

*Edit.* To this sum we can now add:

**4) If $\boldsymbol{k}$ is a field, then the ring $\boldsymbol{R=k[X,Y]/(XY)}$ has non-isomorphic aic's.**

Here, $\mathrm{min}(R)$ $=$ $\{\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}\}$, with $\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $(X)$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ $=$ $(Y)$, if we denote the images of $X$ and $Y$ in $R$ by the same symbols. And $K/\mathfrak{p}K$ $=$ $k(Y)$, with algebraic closure $C_\mathfrak{p}$. The image of $R$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}$ is the polynomial ring $k[Y]$. Let $T_\mathfrak{p}$ be the integral closure of $k[Y]$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}$, and $T_\mathfrak{q}$ the integral closure of $k[X]$ in $C_\mathfrak{q}$ $\cong_k$ $C_\mathfrak{p}$ (under $X\mapsto Y$). We then have $T$ $=$ $T_\mathfrak{p}\times T_\mathfrak{q}$ in $C_\mathfrak{p}\times C_\mathfrak{q}$ $=$ $\overline{K}$.

If $\overline{k}$ is the algebraic closure of $k$, there are ring homomorphisms $T_\mathfrak{p}
\xrightarrow{\varphi}\overline{k}
\xleftarrow{\psi}T_\mathfrak{q}$ extending the maps $\varphi:k[Y]\to \overline{k}\gets k[X]:\psi$ defined by $Y\mapsto$$\,0\,$↤$\,X$. For, the algebraic closure $C_\mathfrak{p}$ results from the field $k(Y)$ by a transfinite series of field extensions, indexed by some ordinal number $\alpha$ (which we can take to be $\omega$ $=$ $\aleph_0$ or the cardinal number of $k$, whichever is the largest of the two, for that must be the cardinality of the field $C_\mathfrak{p}$). When $\gamma$ $\le$ $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, the $\gamma$-th step simply consists of taking the union of the fields constructed in the earlier steps, plus taking the union of the maps $\varphi$ constructed. And when $\gamma$ $=$ $\beta+1$ is a successor ordinal, this step is the adjunction of a new algebraic element to the current field $F_\beta$. By the induction hypothesis, we then have $\varphi:I_\beta\to\overline{k}$, where $I_\beta$ is the set of integers of $F_\beta$ over $k[Y]$, and $F_\gamma$ $=$ $F_\beta[Z]/(g)$ for some monic irreducible $g$ $=$ $g(Z)$ $\in$ $F_\beta[Z]$. If $u$ $\in$ $I_\gamma-I_\beta$ is a new integer and $f$ $\in$ $F_\beta[Z]$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $F_\beta$, its coefficients are in $I_\beta$. (They are elementary symmetric functions in the conjugates of $u$ over $F_\beta$, and each of the latter is integral over $I_\beta$.) Then $u$ can be identified with $Z\text{ mod }f$ $\in$ $I_\beta[Z]/(f)$. Take a $v$ in $\overline{k}$ that is a zero of the image of $f$ in $\overline{k}[Z]$ under $\varphi$. Note that the homomorphism $\varphi:I_\beta[Z]/(f)\to\overline{k}$, for which $Z\text{ mod }f\mapsto v$ and $\varphi\upharpoonright I_\beta:I_\beta\to\overline{k}$ is the map already built, is well defined. It is now clear that $\varphi$ extends to $\varphi:I_\gamma\to\overline{k}$. Ultimately, for $\gamma$ $=$ $\alpha$, we obtain the desired $\varphi:T_\mathfrak{p}$ $=$ $I_\alpha\to\overline{k}$. And we can let $\psi:T_\mathfrak{q}\to\overline{k}$ be the composition $T_\mathfrak{q}\overset{\sim}{\underset{\text{nat}}{\to}}T_\mathfrak{p}\underset{\varphi}{\to}\overline{k}$.

Now let $T_0=\{(u,v)\in T=T_\mathfrak{p}\times T_\mathfrak{q}\mid\varphi(u)=\psi(v)\}$ be the pullback. It contains the image of $R$ in $T$. Indeed, every $r$ $\in$ $R$ is of the form $\lambda+Xf(X)+Yg(Y)$ with $\lambda$ $\in$ $k$ and $f$ and $g$ are univariate polynomials. This maps to $(\lambda+Yg(Y),\lambda+Xf(X))$ in $R/\mathfrak{p}\times R/\mathfrak{q}$ $=$ $k[Y]\times k[X]$ $\subseteq$ $T$, and thence to $(\lambda,\lambda)$ in $\overline{k}\times\overline{k}$ under $\varphi\times\psi$, since $\varphi(Y)$ $=$ $0$ $=$ $\psi(X)$. And $T_0$ is integral and tight over $R$. For let $t_0$ $=$ $(u,v)$ $\in$ $T_0-R$. Say $u$ $\ne$ $0$. Then $Yt_0$ $=$ $(Yu,0)$ is in $T_0-\{0\}$, and we have $f(u)$ $=$ $0$ for some monic $f$ $=$ $f(Z)$ $\in$ $k[Y][Z]$ with $f(0)$ $\in$ $k[Y]$ non-zero, for example for the minimal polynomial $f$ of $u$ over $k(Y)$. If $f^\bullet$ $\in$ $R[X]$ denotes the same polynomial $f$ $\in$ $k[Y][Z]$ $\subseteq$ $R[Z]$, then $g$ $:=$ $Y^{\mathrm{deg}(f)}f^\bullet(Y^{-1}Z)$ $\in$ $R[Z]$ has $g(Yu)$ $=$ $0$ in $T_\mathfrak{p}$ and $g(0)$ = $Y^{\mathrm{deg}(f)}f(0)$ $\ne$ $0$. But $Y$ $=$ $0$ in $T_\mathfrak{q}$, so $g(0)$ vanishes in $T_\mathfrak{q}$, hence $g(Yt_0)$ $=$ $0$ in $T_0$. This shows that $0$ $\ne$ $g(0)$ is in $Yt_0T_0\cap R$ $\subseteq$ $t_0T_0\cap R$.

Finally, $T_0$ is an absolutely integrally closed ring. For let $f$ $\in$ $T_0[Z]$ be monic, of degree $n$, say. Then $f$ $=$ $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(Z-(u_i,v_i))$ in $T[Z]$ for suitable $u_i$ $\in$ $T_\mathfrak{p}$ and $v_i$ $\in$ $T_\mathfrak{q}$, as $T$ is absolutely integrally closed. But then $f$ $=$ $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(Z-(u_i,v_{\pi(i)}))$ in $T[Z]$ $=$ $(T_\mathfrak{p}\times T_\mathfrak{q})[Z]$ for every permutation $\pi$ of the indices $1,\cdots,n$. For $i$ $<$ $n$, let $(a_i,b_i)$ $\in$ $T_0$ be the coefficient of $Z^i$ in $f$. So $(a_0,b_0)$ $=$ $(-1)^n\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(u_i,v_i)$, and so on, up to $(a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$ $=$ $-\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}(u_i,v_i)$. Then we have $(-1)^n\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}\varphi(u_i)$ $=$ $\varphi(a_0)$ $=$ $\psi(b_0)$ $=$ $(-1)^n\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}\psi(v_i)$, and so forth, up to $-\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\varphi(u_i)$ $=$ $\varphi(a_{n-1})$ $=$ $\psi(b_{n-1})$ $=$ $-\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\psi(v_i)$. It follows that in the ring $\overline{k}[Z]$ we have the equality $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(Z-\varphi(u_i))$ $=$ $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}(Z-\psi(v_i))$, and hence $\varphi(u_i)$ $=$ $\psi(v_{\pi(i)})$ for all $i$, for some permutation $\pi$.

So $T_0$ is an aic of $R$. But since $e_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ $=$ $(1,0)$ is not in $T_0$, the rings $T_0$ and $T$ cannot be isomorphic. One is connected, while the other is not. Quod demonstrandum erat, et nunc demonstratum *est*.

**Edit** A paper based on the answer is now on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06738).

Comment: I am also confused, as $R$ is not an extension of $\mathbb Z$, since $4=2x^2=0$ in $R$...

Comment: @Matthé Thanks a lot for the revision of your answer! I will read it later. And it's really awesome that you can prove uniqueness for such a huge class of rings.

Comment: Your proof is great! I was wondering if we can put it in a more conceptual framework. We have two basic facts which I have added to the question. Now, is there a general property of ring maps $R \to R'$ which allow us to deduce a unique a.i.c. for $R$ from a unique a.i.c. of $R'$? This property should be applied to the maps $R \to K$ and the map $K \to \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \in \mathrm{min}(K)} K/\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: I'm wondering if it can be generalized to the situation where $\operatorname{min}(R)$ is compact, maybe replacing $K$ with the complete ring of quotients, or assuming $K$ is von Neumann regular.  See https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-83/issue-2/Annihilation-of-ideals-in-commutative-rings/pjm/1102784515.pdf

Comment: I just saw your newest edit. So the error in the proof is when you say that the image of $S$ in $K$ must be the integral closure of $R$? Can you perhaps strike through the part of the proof which is not correct?

Comment: It might be a good idea to have a longer think about this problem, say a few weeks, and sort out your thoughts and write them out in a stable form, rather than editing this answer every time you find something to update. Each edit bumps this question to the front page, and the platform software is flagging this as unusual activity.

Comment: That is quite true, and you are understandably annoyed by the resulting overhead. I offer the readers my sincere apologies for the inconvenience these countless edits must have caused. And, excited as I was, I should have taken more time to think things through throroughly before posting yet another version which I deemed faultless, only to realize later it in fact wasn't. The present version is now stable,, though.  There is, however, one final edit in the making, to clarify a point I think still is in need of clarification. But, x my heart, that will be my very last edit to this thread.

Comment: I wish I had known these frequent updates, often just for the purpose of correcting the merest triviality, were so publicly visible. Next time, I shall take great care to prevent my eagerness to show off being so blatantly obvious.

Comment: Sharing sentiments of the comment by @JesseElliott - in somewhat orthogonal direction, maybe I am completely off the road but I have vague feeling that absence of nontrivial idempotents could also help? Or maybe move over the Pierce spectrum and do some sort of relative statement... (Excellent answer, by the way, I would not worry much about frequent edits, it is understandable, the answer is quite involved, so many things going on)

Comment: A nice class of rings generalizing the integral domains is the rings $R$ for which the total quotient ring $K = T(R)$ is von Neumann regular (= absolutely flat = weak global dimension 0 = reduced and Krull dimension 0).  $K$ is von Neumann regular iff $R$ is reduced and every prime containing only zerodivisors is minimal. Assuming also that $K$ is semi local, i.e. that $K$ has finitely many primes containing only zerodivisors (thus, finitely minimal primes) amounts to assuming that $K$ is reduced, semilocal, and 0-dimensional, i.e. $K$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields.

Comment: Banishing idempotents in $K$ is kind of orthogonal to this, since when you do that also then you are in the case where $K$ is a field.

Comment: @JesseElliott. That is right, it suffices to have $K$ VNR (implying reducedness of $R$), for $S$ to embed in $T$. My answer started out with $R$ having finite minimal prime spectrum, since I thought I could show aic unicity for such $R$. But the proof could not be completed satisfactorally. Thanks for your suggestion regarding orthogonal idempotents. (I realized yesterday $S$ needs to contain all idempotents in order that $S$ $=$ $T$, and I was in the middle of formulating things when you pipped me to the post.

Comment: I have decided to remove all irrelevant or incorrect stuff and edit markers cluttering up the post, even though etiquette prescribes to leave it alone or use strike-throughs.

Comment: The constructions available for aic's all use the axiom of choice, without which one even cannot prove that every non-trivial ring has a maximal ideal. The precise ring structure of the resulting aic is not clear, and is not easily controllable by tweaking the construction. Absolutely integrally closed rings are never actually absolutely integrally closed, for you can simply adjoin an idempotent or some other integral element, and embed the resulting ring in a ring that is "absolutely integrally closed". (Tightening over $R$, though, all of these new integers will disappear again.)

Comment: When $K$ is VNR, the proof that $T/R$ is tight is no longer valid. I note there that the product of the minimal primes $\neq$ $\mathfrak{p}$ cannot be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$. But when $R$ has infinitely many minimals, this product is not defined.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე $R=k[X,Y]/(XY)$ hasn't got any non-trivial idempotents. It is reduced and has two minimal primes. So $T$ will have four idempotents. But why could't there be an aic of $R$ with just two? That is the essence of the uniqueness question.Idempotents are unavoidable in the creation of an aic. Passing from $R$ to $R[X]/(f)$ to adjoin a root of a monic, the new ring can' be a domain, as $R$ isn't. So $f$ isn't a prime element of $R[X]$, even if it is irreducible. Any $g$ $\in$ $R[X]$ that is $\equiv$ $g^2$ mod $f$ gives an idempotent. (Contd.)

Comment: Tightening the absolutely integrally closed ring over $R$ that results in the end, most of its idempotents will go away, since only four can remain in the aic. But we cannot determine  whether or not there will be two left or four. Note that $g-g^2$ $\in$ $(f)$ doesn't imply $g$ or $1-g$ is in $(f)$, since $f$ is not a prime element.

Comment: I strongly agree with @DavidRoberts here. I find it a bit frustrating to catch up with all the edits, many per day. (Actually, I gave up and will probably read the answer in a few weeks, hoping it is final then.) Also, the topic has become clearly more than just a random question, it is a project, it may become a paper, where lots of discussion is required. The comment section below a post is not the best place for this, and a post is not the best place to present the most recent update. Can we continue this somewhere? That being said, I appreciate all your great work on this question, Matthé!

Comment: Sorry to hear so. Some of my comments were in response to a few good suggestions. Noticing issues with them, I felt I should reply. Viz. 1 that even if $K$ lacks idempotents, they show up in $T$. And 2 that for a general VNR $K$, the ring $T$ is not tight over $R$. But I could of course just have written them down for later. If you prefer, I could delete the comments, and incorporate their gist in the answer. Below, I will make one more point. I have given the matter much thought, and this point is relevant to the problem. I will post it tomorrow, for you to catch up on at your convenience.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. Missed the "can we continue this somewhere" bit. As long as it is not about my perceived misbehaviour, that would be fine. In that case, how would we proceed?

Comment: @MatthévanderLee not so much "perceived misbehaviour" as encouraging a smoother experience for everyone. Point taken you weren't aware of the high level of visibility of the edits. I didn't see your response to me earlier, unfortunately. It's really cool that this question is generating research, and I hope we can see a summary of the result when it's stable.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the answer is stable. There will be no further updates.  Unless someone comes up with a proof that every aic (for the rings $R$ at hand) must contain all mandatory idempotents, or comes up with a counterexample to that, this may be all there is to say concerning this special case.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee Can we perhaps discuss this via email? I could not find your email, but my mail is in my MO profile and I am happy to hear from you.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I've just sent you a mai message, pls confirm it has reached you ok.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work for a counterexample? [EDIT: NO, IT DOES NOT. See comments.]

Let $\bar{\mathbb Z}$ be the ring of all algebraic integers in a fixed algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$. (Surely this is an a.i.c. of $\mathbb Z$ in your sense.) Let $R$ be the fiber product ${\mathbb Z}\times_{\mathbb Z/p}{\mathbb Z}$ for some prime number $p$.

I think that $\bar{\mathbb Z}\times_{\bar{\mathbb Z}/p}\bar{\mathbb Z}$ is then an a.i.c. of $R$.

On the other hand, you can make a "twisted" version $\tilde R$ of this, by choosing an isomorphism $\varphi: \bar{\mathbb Z}/p\cong \bar{\mathbb Z}/p$ that is not the mod $p$ reduction of any isomorphism $\bar{\mathbb Z}\cong \bar{\mathbb Z}$ and then letting $\tilde R$ be the subring of $\bar{\mathbb Z} \times \bar{\mathbb Z}$ consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ such that the class of $y$ in $\bar{\mathbb Z}/p$ is $\varphi$ of the class of $x$.

To make such a map $\varphi$ (for some $p$), you can first choose a cubic Galois extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ and then choose a $p$ that splits in $K$. Then if $\mathcal O_K$ is the maximal order, $\mathcal O_K/p$ is the product of three copies of $\mathbb Z/p$. Choose an automorphism of this product, using a permutation (a $2$-cycle) that is not in the Galois group. This can be extended to an automorphism of $\bar{\mathbb Z}/p$.

Comment: Why does such a $\varphi$ exist?

Comment: I have now edited to indicate why.

Comment: I'm afraid the ring $\bar{\mathbb Z}\times_{\bar{\mathbb Z}/7}\bar{\mathbb Z}$ is not absolutely integrally closed. If $(\alpha,\beta)$ were a zero of $X^2-(7,28)$, then $\alpha$ $=$ $\pm\sqrt{7}$ and $\beta$ $=$ $\pm2\sqrt{7}$, so that $\alpha-\beta$ $\notin$ $7\bar{\mathbb Z}$. The same goes for any prime $p$. If the coefficients of the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are congruent mod $p$ and these polynomials are of the same degree $n$, then $\alpha^n-\beta^n$ $\in$ $p\bar{\mathbb Z}$. But this does not imply that $\alpha-\beta$ $\in$ $p\bar{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @ Matthe: Oh! Well, back to the drawing board. Do you have an idea of what an a. i. c. of that ring would be?

Comment: I am not sure whether it helps to rewrite this ring as $R=\mathbb Z[T]/(T(T-p))$, which becomes a product after localizing at $p$, and if we modulo $p$, we get $R/p=\mathbb F_p[T]/(T^2)$, It might be start with studying a.i.c. rings containing $R/p$.